# How to count object elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a array with objects inside. I count the object values.
The script is working. Is it possible to make it a little bit shorter(DRY) ?

```
var myData = [
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 100, farbigkeit40: "A90ZUKOs4599", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs18dp", quan: 100 },
    { sku: "9017WAs18dp", quan: 50, eindruck: "A90ZUKOs4799" },
    { sku: "9017WAs18dp", quan: 40, eindruck: "A90ZUKOs4799", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 200, farbigkeit44:"A90ZUKOs4699", proof: "A90ZUKOs4499" },
    { sku: "9017WKs43dp", quan: 200, farbigkeit40:"A90ZUKOs4599" }
];

    function countElements() {
        var res = {};
        myData.forEach(function(value){

            res[value.sku]=res[value.sku]||{quan:0};
            res[value.sku].quan+=1*value.quan;

            if(value.farbigkeit40 != undefined) {
                res[value.farbigkeit40] = res[value.farbigkeit40] || {quan:0};
                res[value.farbigkeit40].quan +=1;   
            }
            if(value.farbigkeit44 != undefined) {
                res[value.farbigkeit44] = res[value.farbigkeit44] || {quan:0};
                res[value.farbigkeit44].quan +=1;   
            }
            if(value.proof != undefined) {
                res[value.proof] = res[value.proof] || {quan:0};
                res[value.proof].quan +=1;  
            }
            if(value.eindruck != undefined) {
                res[value.eindruck] = res[value.eindruck] || {quan:0};
                res[value.eindruck].quan +=1;   
            }
        });
        return res;
    }
    console.log(countElements());
    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(countElements(),null,4));
```

With a second `forEach` inside. I have tried this but i didn't get the same result.

```
["farbigkeit40","farbigkeit44","proof","eindruck"].forEach(function(p) {
            res[value.p]=res[value.p] || {quan:0};
            res[value.p].quan += 1;
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of `value.p` you should use `value[p]`.

`object.prop` references to the proprty with the name `prop` within `object` .

`object[prop]` references to the property with the name 'value of' `prop` within `object`.

E.g. `p = 'farbigkeit44'`: `value[p]` is the same as `value['farbigkeit44']` is the same as `value.farbigkeit44`.